# Storing classes in boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost

Someone recommended me to use boost::variant as shape variable to store different types of shapes in it. But, when implemented boost::variant to my code, I got an error while compiling. Error says: 'Shape': base class undefined and more errors.

Here is my code (Object.h):

```
using Shape = boost::variant<Rectangle, Circle>;

enum Shape_Type
{
    RECTANGLE,
    CIRCLE
};

struct Position
{
    float x, y;

    Position(float position_x, float position_y)
    {
        x = position_x;
        y = position_y;
    }
};

class Object : private Shape
{

private:
    std::string name;

public:
    Object() = default;

    Object(std::string name, Rectangle rectangle) : name(name), Shape(rectangle)
    {
    }

    Object(std::string name, Circle circle) : name(name), Shape(circle)
    {
    }

    void setPosition(float, float);

    void setAngle(float);

    Shape* getShape()
    {
        Shape* shape = this;
        return shape;
    }

    Position getPosition();

    const std::string* getName()
    {
        return &name;
    }
};

class Rectangle
{

private:
    sf::RectangleShape rectangleshape;

public:
    Rectangle() = default;

    Rectangle(float width, float height)
        : rectangleshape(sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f(width, height)))
    {
    }

    void setPosition(float position_x, float position_y)
    {
        rectangleshape.setPosition(position_x, position_y);
    }

    void setAngle(float angle)
    {
        rectangleshape.setRotation(angle);
    }

    sf::RectangleShape* getRectangleShape()
    {
        return &rectangleshape;
    }

    Position getPosition()
    {
        return Position(rectangleshape.getPosition().x,
                        rectangleshape.getPosition().y);
    }
};

class Circle
{

private:
    sf::CircleShape circleshape;

public:
    Circle() = default;

    Circle(std::string name, float radius)
        : circleshape(sf::CircleShape(radius))
    {
    }

    void setPosition(float position_x, float position_y)
    {
        circleshape.setPosition(position_x, position_y);
    }

    void setAngle(float angle)
    {
        circleshape.setRotation(angle);
    }

    sf::CircleShape* getCircleShape()
    {
        return &circleshape;
    }

    Position getPosition()
    {
        return Position(circleshape.getPosition().x,
                        circleshape.getPosition().y);
    }
};
```

And btw is getShape() function good?

Answer (score 1):

Variants are used for static polymorphism, so you don't need the base class at all (that's dynamic - or virtual - polymorphism).

The members in a variant typically do not share a common base class, so you wouldn't have the `getShape` function, or you'd need to template it:

```
template <typename T>
T const& getShape() const { return boost::get<T>(_shape); }
```